# LARAVEL 7 || Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-7

I tried to get the name from the author table but this error always happens. What should I do?

**MODEL**
*App\Book*

```
public function author()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Author');
    }
```

*App\Author*

```
public function book()
{
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Book');
}
```

**Views**
*Author/show...*

```
   @php 
        $book = Book::with('author')->where('author_id',$author->id)->get();
   @endphp`
   @foreach ($book as $data)

       ...
          Author name : {{$data->author_id->name}}
       ...

   @endforeach
```

Comment: That's just the name of the book table not from the author table

Comment: I Solved the problem thank for your help. It just like `$data->author->name` no need use a Id

Comment: As a sidenote, it's not recommended to do any heavy operations (such as database queries) within the view. Instead do those in the controller or a separate library that is called by the controller and pass the results to the view.

Comment: I had the same problem. ```{{ $user->employee->emp_name }}```. I declare properly in my models and in my controller, this is my query ```User::get()```

Answer (score 2):

Change code in view like this :

`...
   $data->author->name
...`

do not use "id"